# getElementsByTagName() - Only want select elements, not all

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lets say my page has 10 "li" elements.

If I use `getElementsByTagName("li")`, I will get all 10 elements on the entire page.

Instead of getting all of them.

How can I just get those from a certain area on the page?

```
let allListElements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0;i<allListElements.length;i++){
    console.log(all[i].innerText);
}
```

That shows me all list elements, but I don't want all of them. I only want them from a certain area of the page.

edit: There is no parent that surrounds the specific area that contains the lists. I can't edit the HTML because I am doing web scraping

```
<ul style="list-style-image: url(/images/icon/icon-bullet-orange-arrow_small.png); margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;padding-left:17px;">

                <li style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <a data-tag="linkResult" id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl01_linkResult" class="CsLinkButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$resultsRepeater$ctl01$linkResult", "", true, "", "JobDetails.aspx?site=1&amp;id=1985", false, true))'>J2EE Developer</a>
                    <span class="FieldValue">&nbsp;-&nbsp;( <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl01_displayFields_ctl01_displayField" dolocalize="false">req1985</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl01_displayFields_ctl03_displayField" dolocalize="false">Regular Full-Time</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl01_displayFields_ctl05_displayField" dolocalize="false"></span>&nbsp;)</span>
                </li>

                <li style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <a data-tag="linkResult" id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl02_linkResult" class="CsLinkButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$resultsRepeater$ctl02$linkResult", "", true, "", "JobDetails.aspx?site=1&amp;id=192", false, true))'>Penetration Test Analyst</a>
                    <span class="FieldValue">&nbsp;-&nbsp;( <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl02_displayFields_ctl01_displayField" dolocalize="false">req192</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl02_displayFields_ctl03_displayField" dolocalize="false">Regular Full-Time</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl02_displayFields_ctl05_displayField" dolocalize="false"></span>&nbsp;)</span>
                </li>

                <li style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <a data-tag="linkResult" id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl03_linkResult" class="CsLinkButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$resultsRepeater$ctl03$linkResult", "", true, "", "JobDetails.aspx?site=1&amp;id=2839", false, true))'>Senior J2EE Developer</a>
                    <span class="FieldValue">&nbsp;-&nbsp;( <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl03_displayFields_ctl01_displayField" dolocalize="false">req2839</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl03_displayFields_ctl03_displayField" dolocalize="false">Regular Full-Time</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl03_displayFields_ctl05_displayField" dolocalize="false"></span>&nbsp;)</span>
                </li>

                <li style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    <a data-tag="linkResult" id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl04_linkResult" class="CsLinkButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$resultsRepeater$ctl04$linkResult", "", true, "", "JobDetails.aspx?site=1&amp;id=1703", false, true))'>Software Dev-Object Oriented</a>
                    <span class="FieldValue">&nbsp;-&nbsp;( <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl04_displayFields_ctl01_displayField" dolocalize="false">req1703</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl04_displayFields_ctl03_displayField" dolocalize="false">Regular Full-Time</span> | <span id="ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_resultsRepeater_ctl04_displayFields_ctl05_displayField" dolocalize="false"></span>&nbsp;)</span>
                </li>

                </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please share what is that `certain area on a page`

Comment: use `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Could you please mention, if you have any parent class or id wrapped up in that particular area of the page ?

Comment: so select them from the part of the page..... If there an id, class, etc.... we need to know what is different....

Comment: Where is HTML code ?

Comment: When you'll define "_certain area_", you also know the answer to your question.

Comment: instead of `document` use the certain area `id/class`

Comment: There is no parent id or class that is surrounding that area. See original edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```js
function Change() {
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
a.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].innerHTML = "2";
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="Change();">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! However, I'm trying to loop though the "li", rather than index 0. It's not working for me. This is what I've tried:     var a = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){ var b = a.getElementsByTagName("li")[i]; }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "document", use a specific parent node.

```
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>Data</li>
     ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

In your script, use the node instead of document object.

```
var demo = document.querySelector("#demo");
var li = demo.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

You should get only the "li" in that group.  Hope this is what you're trying to ask.

Happy coding.

Comment: There is no parent that surrounds the specific area that contains the lists. I can't edit the HTML because I am doing web scraping.

Comment: Hmmm...I am almost certain there's got to be a parent tag somewhere.  The parent tag pair doesn't have to be immediately next to them.  As long as the "li" elements are wrapped inside another container tag, you can narrow it down to only that section.  If there are absolutely no parent container tags, that's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

put class="testLiClass" id= on your < li> elements and try finding with the below
basic JQuery/CSS selector:

var testLi =  $("ul").find( "#.testLiClass" );

i.e  if your code looks something like
....

then you can idnetify the li you are looking for with below code:

var testLiControl =  $("ul").find( "#1.testClass" );